# Frame Buttons Aren't Visible

Tags: java, swing

I have a that is supposed to be an "Layouts" example. A Simple program that when the user clicks the buttons it will change the layout of the frame.
It was working fine until I added the last two other frames now when I run it the buttons are missing. I've checked and checked and can't find the problem. Can someone help please?

```
    public class FrameLayouts {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("FlowLayout");
        final JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("GridLayout");
        final JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("BorderLayout");

        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setVisible(false);
        frame3.setVisible(false);


        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(500,500);
        frame1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button1 = new JButton ("Grid Layout");
        JButton button2 = new JButton ("Border Layout");
        JButton button3 = new JButton ("Flow Layout");
        JButton button4 = new JButton ("EXTRA");
        JButton button5 = new JButton ("EXTRA");

        frame1.add(button4);
        frame1.add(button1);
        frame1.add(button2);
        frame1.add(button3);
        frame1.add(button5);
        frame1.pack();

        frame2.add(button4);
        frame2.add(button1);
        frame2.add(button2);
        frame2.add(button3);
        frame2.add(button5);
        frame2.pack();

        frame3.add(button4, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame3.add(button1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame3.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame3.add(button3, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame3.add(button5, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame3.pack();


        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame2.setSize(500,500);
                frame2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));

                frame3.setVisible(false);
                frame1.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame3.setVisible(true);
                frame3.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame3.setSize(500,500);
                frame3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));

                frame1.setVisible(false);
                frame2.setVisible(false);

            }
        });

        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                frame1.setVisible(true);
                frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame1.setSize(500,500);
                frame1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                frame2.setVisible(false);
                frame3.setVisible(false);

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you cannot add the same button to more than one container. When you add it to the second frame it's removed from the first.

Just create copy of the buttons for each frame instance.